# comparing 2 different sql tables in sql inserting into new table

Tags: mysql

i have created two different tables in the MySQL ,both the tables are entirely different from each other .
now i need to compare these two tables and I've to pass the variables into another  new table.

Comment: Searching info for the 2 tables. . . Loading . . . Result -> 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:
CREATE TABLE SALARY AS
   SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;

Comment: okay.. I will give an idea for doing this.. First you generate auto increment id for both the table's and then update  all the field record from second table to first table by comparing that auto increment id.... just try this..

Comment: i have two tables of different parameters in that ,where i have to concatenate those two tables and i have to put the result in a new table(3rd table). while concatenating the result should be in (table1 value- table2 value) this manner .